# I need to print two lists, 50 characters at a time, alternating between lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, traversal

I have two lists, and one is based on the other. I want to print 50 items/line from each list, alternating between lists. I am able to get it with one list, but introducing the second list, and alternating back and forth I can't figure out. I'm have this so far:

```
while idx < len(_back_check):
    print (_back_check[idx], end="") 
    if ((idx > 0) and (idx % 50 == 0)): 
        print() break; 
    idx +=1
```

As an example, if I have 2 lists, `l1=[.......]` and `l2=[........]`, I need an output:

```
l1[0]-l1[49]
l2[0]-l2[49]
l1[50]-l1[99]
l2[50]-l2[99]
l1[100]-l1[149]......
```

I hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: Please post the code you have right now.

Comment: Also, if you're new, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question.

Comment: while idx < len(_back_check):
   'print (_back_check[idx], end="")
    if ((idx > 0) and (idx % 50 == 0)):
        print()
        break;
    idx +=1'

Comment: @AliMojabi Please add the code in your comment, correctly formatted, to your original post. Use indents to create code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 lists `first_list` and `second_list` with same size:

```
for i in range(0, len(first_list), 50):
    print(*first_list[i:i+50])
    print(*second_list[i:i+50])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! can you tell me how to remove the spaces between the letters? I know the `*` takes the commas and apostrophes but there's still space there.

Comment: @AliMojabi you can use `print(*first_list[i:i+50], sep="")`

Comment: Ingenious, it took me a sec to get why you were doing the `range(0, len(first_list), 50):`, but i see now how it ties in with the range you set within the lists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A longer solution than @AlirezaMika but can dynamically handle any number of parallel lists:

```
l1 = 'A' * 1035
l2 = 'B' * len(l1)
l3 = 'C' * len(l1)

my_lists = [l1, l2, l3]

SEGMENT = 50

for index in range(0, len(my_lists[0]), SEGMENT):
    for offset in range(len(my_lists)):
        my_list = my_lists[offset]
        print(*my_list[index:index + SEGMENT], sep="")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',....]
list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', ...]
count = 0
d1 = []
d2 = []
for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2):
    d1.append(l1)
    d2.append(l2)
    count += 1
    if not count % 50:
        print(",".join(d1))
        print(",".join(d2))
        d1 = []
        d2 = []

Output:
a,b,c,d,e,f, .... 50th
1,2,3,4,5,6 ..... 50th

Again it will show next 50 items 

Totals rows: 120x2
```

Comment: that's not quite it. I tried `zip()` already, but it does columns with the lists, not rows. also, my lists are 6000 items long each, so I need ~120 x 2 rows printed.

Comment: that almost there, but when it appends to `d1` and `d2` the list keeps getting longer, and then it prints the entire list the next round.

Comment: This code doesn't run due to the lack of a colon after `if not count % 50`

Comment: I did answer from phone. but check now and i think now code will work as you want.